# how to access local server "wamp" in mobile(Android or iOS) both

Tags: server, wamp, local

I am using wamp on my laptop as a local server and i want to access it on my android and iOS device in order to test my web application, i have already tried by using ipv4 address but its not working, how to do it? Please describe. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try local tunnelling services like [ngrok](https://www.ngrok.com)...their documentation is easy to understand.